# Tumblr theme tag block ignores first tag

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

The code for caption and tags seems normal:

```
{block:Caption}
<div style="margin-top:10px;">{Caption}</div>
{/block:Caption}

{block:HasTags}
{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}>#{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}
{/block:hasTags}
```

and yet on the actual theme itself, the first tag is always missing. So, posts tagged with only one thing will appear without tags, and posts with several will begin from tag #2. I cannot find where this is originating from. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it's a piece of CSS unintentionally hiding it.

We'd have to see the page in action to figure it out (either link to your blog that uses the theme, and/or link to the theme you're using), then I can edit this post if I find the problem.